# Can I still be respawned if I die by falling off the map?

Tags: apex-legends

I've been playing Apex Legends for a while, but apparently I still need more practice because I keep making a very newbish mistake: falling off the map. I'm usually trying to jump over a ledge to get cover during an intense fight, and don't realize that the ledge is actually a leathal cliff. My teammates have always died shortly after, but I'm wondering whether it would be possible for them to respawn me if they did survive.

Is it somehow possible for teammates to respawn you after you die by falling off the map? Does your deathbox appear back on the map, or does it still appear next to your out-of-bounds corpse?

A similar scenario I experienced: I died on the edge of the map (in bounds), but my deathbox fell off the map after spawning. If the deathbox does normally spawn in-bounds, would it be respawned back in bounds if it falls off the map, or am I definitely out of luck in that case?

Comment: When you're dead and waiting for a respawn, you can press the jump button to ping your banner, or the nearest beacon if your banner has already been fetched. If your teammates manage to last ten seconds longer than you, you can check what happened to your death box.

Comment: Also, side note: if you're having trouble with falling off the map, land north or center, where there are no cliffs.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From personal experience, yes you can be respawned if you die from falling off the map. I accidentally ran off the side when trying to dodge a grenade inside a smoke bomb, and my box spawned on the map, near the edge and my teammates were able to grab my banner and respawn me. I have also recovered several of my teammates banners and respawned them after they jumped off the edge.

If someone managed to push your box off the edge after it spawned near the edge, I am unsure of how that would be handled. It may respawn back in bounds, or it may be gone forever.